# Displaying Japanese, Chinese, Viatnamese, etc in C++ window menu

Tags: c++, menu, special-characters

I was making a program that could display different languages once pressed, but when it came to making the LPSTR in my menu to display the Japanese option, it wouldn't display the Japanese characters. It just displayed "???".

Here is a screenshot of my program:

[image]

Here is the code that doesn't work:

I tried this:

```
        AppendMenu(win32LANGUAGE,MF_STRING,NULL,"日本人");
```

and this:

```
        wchar_t jap = "日本人"; 
        AppendMenu(win32LANGUAGE,MF_STRING,NULL,(LPSTR)jap);
```

I am stuck. I don't know why it won't display the Japanese characters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reading up on C++ and Unicode would be a good start.

Comment: Copied below as answer.

Comment: you probably meant korean or thai rather than _vietnamese_, the later being based on the latin alphabet augmented with accents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler doesn't throw an error on AppendMenu then you probably haven't defined the `UNICODE` macro, try using `AppendMenuW`, set `jap` (which should be a `wchar_t const*`) to `L"日本語"`, and don't cast it.